# PHP MySql Real Escape String not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to read and write to a database. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$mysql = mysqli_connect("example.com", "johndoe", "abc123"); // replace with actual credidentials
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string("username");
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbname";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_close($mysql);
$mysql = mysqli_connect("example.com", "johndoe", "abc123", "dbname"); // replace with actual credidentials
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID), username CHAR(15), password CHAR(15), email CHAR(50))";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users(username, password, email) VALUES(" . $username . ", " . $password . ", " . $email . ")";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
mysqli_close($mysql);
```

However, when I try to run it, it has an error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , )' at line 1
```

Could anybody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Would like to, but where is there a MySQL_real_escape_string in this program?

Comment: It's spelled "escape", not "excape". :)

Comment: oops, sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_real_escape_string requires connection parameter too...

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,"username");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your second SQL query like this..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Customers(`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";
```

The problem was there was improper escaping.

`Sidenote:` Switching to **`PreparedStatements`** is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: @inf3rno, I agree. Sidenote added.

Answer (score 0):

Use preapred statements: http://hu1.php.net/mysqli_prepare they automatically escape the params...

Btw. the params in your last sql are not properly escaped and concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping characters and making them clean before inserting in database, [you can use below function to santizie them properly](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/sanitize-database-inputs/),

```
<?php
function cleanInput($input) {

  $search = array(
    '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
    '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
    '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
    '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
  );

    $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    return $output;
  }
?>
```

and finally when output, to escape `'` on page, use :

`htmlspecialchars($quote_str, ENT_QUOTES);` or `htmlentities($quote_str, ENT_QUOTES);`